# mongoid-bcrypt-ruby returning invalid hash when trying to persist a new user

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am trying to setup a simple password encryption using `mongoid-bcrypt-ruby` `mongoid` and `sinatra` i am also developing on a windows machine

unfortunately whenever I try to persist a new user i get an error from my `User.create!()` call saying `invalid hash`

```
# gemfile
ruby "2.2.4"
source "http://rubygems.org"
gem "sinatra", require: "sinatra/base"
gem "sinatra-contrib", require: "sinatra/namespace"
gem "rack"
gem "thin"
gem "mongoid"
gem "mongoid-bcrypt-ruby"
```

user model

```
class User

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  store_in collection: :users

  field :first_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String
  field :email, type: String
  field :phone_number, type: String
  field :password, type: BCrypt::Password 

  field :is_active, type: Boolean, default: false
  field :is_admin, type: Boolean, default: false


  # ....

end

class Routes

  # ....

  post '/submit' do
    User.create!(
      first_name: params['first_name'],
      last_name: params['last_name'],
      email: params['email'],
      phone_number: params['phone_number'],
      password: params['password']
    )
  end
end
```

Trace from Sinatra's error page:

```
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash at /api/v1/new_user
invalid hash
file: password.rb location: initialize line: 60
```

Full Backtrace from Sinatra's error page:

```
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt/password.rb in initialize
        raise Errors::InvalidHash.new("invalid hash")
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-bcrypt-ruby-0.0.2/lib/mongoid/bcrypt/ruby.rb in new
        when String then self.new(password)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-bcrypt-ruby-0.0.2/lib/mongoid/bcrypt/ruby.rb in demongoize
        when String then self.new(password)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-6.0.2/lib/mongoid/fields/standard.rb in demongoize
      delegate :demongoize, :evolve, :mongoize, to: :type
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-6.0.2/lib/mongoid/fields.rb in block (2 levels) in create_field_getter
              value = field.demongoize(raw)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-6.0.2/lib/mongoid/validatable.rb in read_attribute_for_validation
        send(attr)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.0.1/lib/active_model/validator.rb in block in validate
        value = record.read_attribute_for_validation(attribute)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.0.1/lib/active_model/validator.rb in each
      attributes.each do |attribute|
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.0.1/lib/active_model/validator.rb in validate
      attributes.each do |attribute|
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb in public_send
            filter.public_send method_to_call, target, &blk
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb in block in make_lambda
            filter.public_send method_to_call, target, &blk
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb in call
              result_lambda = -> { user_callback.call target, value }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb in block (2 levels) in halting
              result_lambda = -> { user_callback.call target, value }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb in call
           result_lambda.call if result_lambda.is_a?(Proc)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb in block (2 levels) in default_terminator
            result_lambda.call if result_lambda.is_a?(Proc)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb in catch
      catch(:abort) do
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb in block in default_terminator
      catch(:abort) do
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb in call
          env.halted = halted_lambda.call(target, result_lambda)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb in block in halting
          env.halted = halted_lambda.call(target, result_lambda)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb in call
    @before.each { |b| b.call(arg) }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb in block in call
    @before.each { |b| b.call(arg) }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb in each
    @before.each { |b| b.call(arg) }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb in call
    @before.each { |b| b.call(arg) }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb in __run_callbacks__
    runner.call(e).value
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb in _run_validate_callbacks
          __run_callbacks__(_#{name}_callbacks, &block)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.0.1/lib/active_model/validations.rb in run_validations!
  _run_validate_callbacks
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.0.1/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb in block in run_validations!
    _run_validation_callbacks { super }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb in __run_callbacks__
    yield if block_given?
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb in _run_validation_callbacks
          __run_callbacks__(_#{name}_callbacks, &block)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.0.1/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb in run_validations!
    _run_validation_callbacks { super }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.0.1/lib/active_model/validations.rb in valid?
  run_validations!
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-6.0.2/lib/mongoid/validatable.rb in valid?
  super context ? context : (new_record? ? :create : :update)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.0.1/lib/active_model/validations.rb in invalid?
  !valid?(context)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-6.0.2/lib/mongoid/persistable/creatable.rb in prepare_insert
      invalid?(options[:context] || :create)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-6.0.2/lib/mongoid/persistable/creatable.rb in insert
    prepare_insert(options) do
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-6.0.2/lib/mongoid/persistable/creatable.rb in block in create!
          doc.fail_due_to_validation! unless doc.insert.errors.empty?
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-6.0.2/lib/mongoid/threaded/lifecycle.rb in _creating
      yield
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-6.0.2/lib/mongoid/persistable/creatable.rb in create!
      _creating do
C:/Users/ALilland/Documents/macros/experiments/mongoid/mongoid_heroku/db_core_app/models/user.rb in block (2 levels) in <class:Routes>
    User.create!(
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call
      proc { |a,p| unbound_method.bind(a).call }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block in compile!
      proc { |a,p| unbound_method.bind(a).call }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in []
        route_eval { block[*args] }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block (3 levels) in route!
        route_eval { block[*args] }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in route_eval
  throw :halt, yield
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block (2 levels) in route!
        route_eval { block[*args] }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block in process_route
    block ? block[self, values] : yield(self, values)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in catch
  catch(:pass) do
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in process_route
  catch(:pass) do
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block in route!
      returned_pass_block = process_route(pattern, keys, conditions) do |*args|
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in each
    routes.each do |pattern, keys, conditions, block|
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in route!
    routes.each do |pattern, keys, conditions, block|
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block in dispatch!
    route!
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block in invoke
  res = catch(:halt) { yield }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in catch
  res = catch(:halt) { yield }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in invoke
  res = catch(:halt) { yield }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in dispatch!
  invoke do
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block in call!
  invoke { dispatch! }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block in invoke
  res = catch(:halt) { yield }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in catch
  res = catch(:halt) { yield }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in invoke
  res = catch(:halt) { yield }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call!
  invoke { dispatch! }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call
  dup.call!(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb in call
    status, headers, body = @app.call(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb in call
    result or app.call(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb in call
    result or app.call(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb in call
    app.call env
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb in call
    status, headers, body = app.call(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb in call
    result or app.call(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb in call
    result or app.call(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/frame_options.rb in call
    status, headers, body        = @app.call(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb in context
      status, headers, body = app.call(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb in call
      context(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/logger.rb in call
  @app.call(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call
  env['sinatra.commonlogger'] ? @app.call(env) : super
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/head.rb in call
status, headers, body = @app.call(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/show_exceptions.rb in call
  @app.call(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call
  result, callback = app.call(env), env['async.callback']
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call
  @stack.call(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block in call
    synchronize { prototype.call(env) }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in synchronize
      yield
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call
    synchronize { prototype.call(env) }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/cascade.rb in block in call
    result = app.call(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/cascade.rb in each
  @apps.each do |app|
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/cascade.rb in call
  @apps.each do |app|
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb in call
  status, headers, body = @app.call(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/lint.rb in _call
  status, headers, @body = @app.call(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/lint.rb in call
  dup._call(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/showexceptions.rb in call
  @app.call(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb in call
  status, header, body = @app.call(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call
    call_without_check(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/chunked.rb in call
  status, headers, body = @app.call(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb in call
  status, headers, body = @app.call(env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/connection.rb in block in pre_process
    response = @app.call(@request.env)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/connection.rb in catch
  catch(:async) do
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/connection.rb in pre_process
  catch(:async) do
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/connection.rb in process
    post_process(pre_process)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/connection.rb in receive_data
  process if @request.parse(data)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.1-x86-mingw32/lib/eventmachine.rb in run_machine
      run_machine
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.1-x86-mingw32/lib/eventmachine.rb in run
      run_machine
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb in start
      EventMachine.run(&starter)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/server.rb in start
  @backend.start { setup_signals if @setup_signals }
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb in run
    server.start
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/server.rb in start
  server.run wrapped_app, options, &blk
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/server.rb in start
  new(options).start
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/bin/rackup in <top (required)>
  Rack::Server.start
C:/Ruby22/bin/rackup in load
  load Gem.bin_path('rack', 'rackup', version)
C:/Ruby22/bin/rackup in <main>
  load Gem.bin_path('rack', 'rackup', version)
```

Comment: can you share the stack trace of the error?

Comment: @emaillenin added error trace

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself. The below worked for me.

You can see from the trace that the problem is the line:

`when String then self.new(password)`

Change that line to the following:

`when String then self.create(password)`